# Converting to Uppercase using assembly language(if statement issue)

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm new to assembly language and I'm having some trouble on some beginner problems. I'm trying to write a function that converts char* from lower to upper case. In my code I've written an if statement to check if the selected character is in between the ascii bounds of lower case characters. I have 2 questions on this matter. One is I keep getting a compiler error on my if statement regarding one of the elses that I use. Second, I plan on iterating through the entire char* converting each character if it follows within the necessary range. Using a loop how would I be able to do that? Any help would be awesome I really appreciate it! Thanks!

```
void toUpper(char *string) {
__asm{

    PUSH EAX
    PUSH EBX
    PUSH ECX
    PUSH EDX
    PUSH ESI
    PUSH EDI

    MOV EBX, string

    /* Your code begins below this line. */

    mov eax, dword ptr[ebx]
    cmp eax, 97d
    jl ELSE
    cmp eax, 122d
    jg ELSE
    sub eax, 32d
    jmp END_IF
    END_IF:





    /* Your code ends above this line. */

    POP EDI
    POP ESI
    POP EDX
    POP ECX
    POP EBX
    POP EAX

}
```

}

Comment: *Quick correction I mixed up the order of jl ELSE and jg ELSE. The jg ELSE should come after the 97d and the jl ELSE should come after the 122d. However, I still receive a compiler error

Comment: `mov eax, dword ptr[ebx]` <-- that's going to give you 4 characters in `eax`, not 1. As for the compilation error; it doesn't seem like you've declared an `ELSE` label anywhere. Also, `cmp eax, 'a'` means the same thing as `cmp eax, 97d` but is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a 32-bit register, namely `EAX`, to compare an explicitly defined 32-bit data addressed by `EBX` (using `dword ptr[ebx]`). You must use 8-bit data, for ASCII characters are always 1 byte in length. So, assuming that the `ELSE` label was already defined somewhere in your program, the correct code would be:

```
void toUpper(char *string) {
__asm{
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx
    push esi
    push edi
    mov ebx, string

    /* Your code begins below this line. */

    mov al, byte ptr[ebx]
    cmp al, 97d
    jl ELSE
    cmp al, 122d
    jg ELSE
    sub eax, 32d
    jmp END_IF
    END_IF:

    /* Your code ends above this line. */

    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax

}
```

Good luck.